# Is it possible to access the Host Protected Area within Windows?

Tags: windows, wmi, hardware, drivers

I am looking at creating an application that can access the HPA of hard drives in Windows.

I can see code to do this in Linux, but nothing in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to send a a number of ATA commands.

See setmax.c for which ones.